# Problem importing Tensorflow Hub "module 'tensorflow.tools.docs.doc_controls' has no attribute 'inheritable_header'"

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6, tensorflow-hub

I am facing an issue regarding the import of TensorFlow hub. Following are the errors which are posted in the terminal. The version of tensorflow, I am using is 2.6, and the version of tensorflow-hub is 0.12.0. I installed both of them using pip install. I have a bit of urgency in completing my project, and I would be really thankful for your help.

```
File "/home/bannigo/catkin_ws/src/motorAI_assign/scripts/task1_1.py", line 21, in
import tensorflow_hub as hub
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/init.py", line 
88, in
from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py",         
line 62, in
class LatestModuleExporter(tf.compat.v1.estimator.Exporter):
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-    
packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 62, in getattr
module = self._load()
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 45, in _load
module = importlib.import_module(self.name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/init.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/init.py", 
line 10, in
from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/init.py", line 10, in
from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow_estimator/_api/v1/estimator/experimental/init.py", line 10, in
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 27, in
from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
File "/home/bannigo/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 70, in
@doc_controls.inheritable_header
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.tools.docs.doc_controls' has no attribute 
'inheritable_header'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/819. One temporary workaround is to downgrade `tensorflow-estimator`:

`pip install -U tensorflow-estimator==2.6.0`